# How would you translate 成就卓越的你 in English?

Tags: translation

Google Translate gives "achieving you",
which obviously sounds weird in English.

I was thinking of "develop your best self"
or "become the best you can be"
or "achieve excellence" (which is what Google Translate gives for 成就卓越).

Answer (score 2):

成就 'achievement' is a noun

卓越 'excellent' would be an adjective in 成就卓越, not the noun 'excellence'

成就卓越 should be translated as "achievement is excellent"

的 as an adjective marker marks 成就卓越 as an adjective phrase that describes the noun 你

成就卓越的你 = "You whose achievement is excellent"

"whose achievement is excellent" is an adjectival phrase that describes "you"

Another example:

> 工作繁忙的他

工作(noun) = job

繁忙 (adjective) = busy

工作繁忙 = job is busy

工作繁忙的 (adjectival phrase) = whose job is busy

他(noun) = he

工作繁忙的(adjectival phrase) describes 他(noun)

工作繁忙的他 = he whose job is busy

Comment: It is tricky as "成就" can be a noun, or a verb, as in 成就大業 = 完(達)成大事.

Comment: How about paraphrasing it as "Achieving excellence is up to you"?

Answer (score 1):

I think that 成就 in this sentence is a verb, it means to make someone successful. Example:

> 成就了今天的我

成就了(verb)=achieved

今天的(adverb)=at the present

我(noun)=me

Can be translated as 'made me who I am today'.

So I think 成就卓越的你 can be translated as 'achieve the outstanding you'.